# Binary Numbers what is the solution V2

Tags: objective-c, binary, binary-data, equation

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem ? any help would be great...... i cant seem to get my head around it.

As you know Binary can  only be either  1 or 0

Say you had a 8 digit Binary number like a byte >>>>>> 0001 1000

Im trying to figure out an equation  or what would be the maximum amount of combinations you could get  from an 8 digit number

What i mean is.... say you had a two digit binary number,the maximum Bnary combinations that  you could have are either

00

01

10

11
Therefore  total maximum combinations from a 2 digit Binary number = 4

Example 2

If you had a 3 digit number , maximum  Binary Combinations would be

000

001

010

100

101

111

110

011
Therefore  total maximum Binary combinations from a 3 digit number = 8

Example 3

If it were a 4 digit number, maximum binary combinations that  you could have are either

0000

0001

0010

0100

1000

0111

0110

1111

1110

1101

1011

1001                  Total maximum combination = 12

I Recently Asked this Question and  it was answered thank you manu-fatto and zgnilec  they were kind enough to let me know it was a simple  equation  the answer/equation is  2^digit size.

I guess my next problem is how  do i write a small program that can show these combinations in  Xcode  or NSLog. I'm good with objective C an output I can view like  NSLog would be great.

All I know is it would look something like:

```
int DigitSize=8
int CombinationTotal = 2^8
CombinationSize = NSMutableArray  ArraywithCapacity 8;
```

Output

```
NSString  Combination1 =@"0000 0000";
NSString  Combination2 =@"0000 0001";
NSString  Combination3 =@"0000 0010";

Nslog @"combination 1 = %@  ,Combination1";
Nslog @"combination 2 = %@  ,Combination2";
Nslog @"combination 3 = %@  ,Combination3";

……

Nslog @"combination 256 = ???? ???? ";
```

Sorry for the vague language I only started learning programming 3 months ago and I still have a lot of tutorials to go through.

**Im trying to build a data compression algorithm...

basically data compression is about reducing the number of bits ... the lesser the bits  the smaller a file is

ie

A file with 700bits  is smaller than a file with 900bits

8 bits = 1 byte

1024bytes = 1kb

1024kb = 1 mb

i donno if its even possible but i just thought  what if  you had an algorithm  that could read 1024 bits at a time ...with the equation thats =     2^1024 = math error     :(  ==    total number of bit combinations possible

Once you have the total number of combinations you set each combination to  a symbol like eg 000101010010101011001011011010101010140010101101000000001110100101100001010100000......0011010 = symbol #

So from now on whenever the computer sees the symbol # it recognises  it is equal to the binary number 000101010010101011001011011010101010140010101101000000001110100101100001010100000......0011010

to better understand it ...just think of number plates on a car/vehicle, they are only a few characters but wen you punch them into police database or any car data base more information comes out its the same principle....

basically the symbols are  a key to more data

i dont know if it make sense but...  in theory  if you could  read  8388608 bits at a time

8388608 bits = 1megabyte  ......

ten symbols could mean 10mb...you could  create digital media  2d barcodes 
its just a thought i had watching starGate lol :)**

Answer (score 4):

2 to the power of 8, where 8 is number of digits.

Edit- only read first question :)

create function that will display an integer as binary

```
for (i = 0; i < pow(2,n), i++)
{
    displayBits(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick implementation

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSUInteger length = 8;  // number of digits
        NSUInteger n = pow(2, length); // number of possible values
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            NSString *repr = @"" ;
            for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j) {
                if([repr length] % 5 == 0)
                    repr = [@" " stringByAppendingString:repr]; // add a blank after evey 4th digit
                int x =( i >> j) &1;
                repr = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u",x] stringByAppendingString:repr];
            }
            NSLog(@"%@", repr);                
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0000 0000 
0000 0001 
0000 0010 
0000 0011 
0000 0100 
0000 0101 
0000 0110 
0000 0111 
0000 1000 
0000 1001 
0000 1010 
0000 1011 
0000 1100 
0000 1101 
0000 1110 
0000 1111 
0001 0000 
…
1110 1100 
1110 1101 
1110 1110 
1110 1111 
1111 0000 
1111 0001 
1111 0010 
1111 0011 
1111 0100 
1111 0101 
1111 0110 
1111 0111 
1111 1000 
1111 1001 
1111 1010 
1111 1011 
1111 1100 
1111 1101 
1111 1110 
1111 1111
```

The core of this program is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //…
    for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j) {
        int x =( i >> j) &1;
        //…
    }
}
```

this will run for i =0 bis (2^n)-1 and in the inner for-loop for every j of the n bits, to check, if the least bit is 1, and append it to the representation string.

As you are a beginner, you probably dont know, what this means: `int x =( i >> j) & 1;`

[`>>` shifts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23) the bits of the left side integer by as many decimal places as the right side defines. and [`& 1` performs a bit wise addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

so for i == 3 and n == 8

```
       3 as binary                         string representation
j = 0: 00000011 >> 0 ->  0000 0011 
                        &0000 0001
                        -----------
                        00000 0001 -> 1     repr = 1

j = 1: 00000011 >> 1 ->   000 0001 
                        &0000 0001
                        -----------
                        00000 0001 -> 1     repr = 11

j = 2: 00000011 >> 2 ->    00 0000
                        &0000 0001
                        -----------
                        00000 0000 -> 0     repr = 011

j = 3: 00000011 >> 3 ->     0 0000 
                        &0000 0001
                        -----------
                        00000 0000 -> 0     repr = 0011

  (the same till j = 7)                     repr = 0000 0011
```

Comment: thanks Vikingosegundo i will try  build the program  tonite  ;) i hope it compiles with no issues or  errors

Comment: and? did it compile and run without issues and errors?

Comment: What did u do? It works fine here.

Comment: I made my complete project available on github: https://github.com/vikingosegundo/binarystring

Comment: I dont get why you want to save anything. This are just string representation of integers, calculate a particular, when you need it.

Comment: I know what a QRCode is. I dont get your statement, why you want to save all possible binary combinations.

Comment: these are just integers represented as strings: create them on the fly when needed. it would be quite crazy to save integers to the disc just to build look up tables. But anyway: you raped your own question instead of including necessary information. I will stop investing more of my time here.

Comment: I mean that you destroyed your question instead of improving it. it is closed already and will be deleted in few days. All the effort I put into answering it will be lost. And you seem not to have the basic understanding of how integer arithmetic is working in a cpu. for the computer there is no difference, if a integer is written as 13 (decimal) or 11101 (binary). So it is absolute stupid to write all integers as strings to the disc. just create a string-representation when u need it. but I am sure you wont get it again.